# Why scrollViewWillBeginDragging in uiTableViewController didn't work?

Tags: ios, scrollview, uitableview

In file .h I have:

```
@protocol VVInformationTableViewControllerDelegate;

@interface VVInformationTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) VVUser* currentAttendee;

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<VVInformationTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

In file .m:

In viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

and I have method:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    [self dismissKeyboard];
    NSLog(@"HEJ");
}
```

But when I dragging my tableView (no matter if keyboard is show or not) this method didn't work. I looked for this problem but I couldn't find asnwer.

EDIT:
I make this (scrollViewWillBeginDragging) method in parentViewController and it works. But when I call in this method in parentViewController [self.infoTableView dismissKeyboard] (VVInformationTableViewController as childViewController) which is in childView It didn't work. For example if I try use dismissKeyboard:

```
- (void)dismissKeyboard {
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.textField.text);
}
```

in childView then self.textField.text in NSLog is good, but when I try call it in parentView then it is nil, so resignFirstResponder on this textfield didn't work.

I make protocol with method dismissKeyboard in .h of childViewController and:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    self.textField = textField;
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: You don't need this self.tableView.delegate = self; as its a subclass of UITableViewController.

Comment: I think you need to post more information, because I don't see why this isn't working with what you've posted so far.

Comment: I need this to dismiss keyboard when I scroll, but istead of when I scroll my tableView is scrolled and keyboard is not disiss. I need this do opposite.

Comment: Or maybe can I do this in parrentViewController, because this controller is childView of controller with uiscrollView.